# counterexample completeness of metric spaces

Tags: analytic-geometry, complete-spaces

I'm looking for a counterexample. I already  proved that if $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces and $X$ is complete and $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection that $Y$ is complete if $f^{-1}$ is uniform continuous. I know that if $f^{-1}$ isn't uniform continuous $Y$ isn't complete. I just can't find a counterexample.

I tried to look for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ or something but it's  never right. I found online that $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,1):x\mapsto1/(1+2^{-x})$ is a counterexample but i don't really see how. Can someone maybe give an easier example or explain me why this is a great counterexample?

Edit: i'm looking for a function with f is uniform continuous and f^-1 is normal continuous, where X is complete but Y isn't

Comment: As an aside, not only can you not find a bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$ but the only continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$ are constant functions. This is because the image of a $\Bbb R$ under a continuous function must be connected but the only connected subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are singletons.

Comment: you're right thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac x {1+|x|}$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto $(-1,1)$. The domain is complete but the range is not.

Alternatively use the homeomorphism $\arctan x$ from $\mathbb R$ onto $(-\pi /2 ,\pi /2)$.

These two functions are uniformly continuous bijections.

Comment: can you explain to me why (-1,1) isn't complete?

Comment: $\{-1+\frac  1 n\}$ is  a Cauchy sequence which does not converge.

Comment: i'm also looking for an isomorphism beceause i want a bijection

Comment: My maps are both bijections.

Comment: oh i'm so sorry , i meant that i need that f is uniform continuous and f^-1 is normal continuous i think forgot to say that

Comment: Both of my functions are also unoformly continuous. In the second case this is immediate since the derivative of $\arctan$ is bounded and we can use MVT.

Comment: thank you then i can try to prove it :)